# Is there a nice clean way of whitelisting inline styles so that they are not blocked by CSP?

Tags: c#, web, .net-6.0, content-security-policy, inline-styles

I have a .NET 6 app written mainly in C#. There are razor pages in the app, where I occasionally need to use inline styles. They get blocked by Content Security Policy, so I was investigating how to whitelist certain styles so they are not blocked. I am aware there are different options for making CSP not block it. Moving stuff to a .CSS file is not an option for me (I use some injected parameters in the style which will not be available in a .CSS).

The other options are to use a nonce or hash on your style, which will be specified in the CSP as safe. Both nonce and hash need to be generated uniquely for every HTTP request.

I was trying to look for a cleaner solution than manually creating a hashing function and generating some nonce on every HTTP request (I am also not sure how I would pass that nonce/hash to the CSP every time), and I was wondering if there is any other solution that is cleaner to implement?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to rewrite and nonces won't work your options are to use hashes (see below) or allow 'unsafe-inline'. 'unsafe-inline' is not recommended, but the dangers can be remediated if you lock down the rest of your CSP, see https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/.

Hashes don't need to be generated every time, you can insert static hash values that will work for styles that match the hash value. If there is a limited number of possible inline styles you could add the hash value for all of them. I would strongly suggest to collect CSP reports using report-to or report-uri directives to identify all such violations that may appear in your app.